# Django: Two questions on extending ListView with get_context_data

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I tried something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027544/how-to-properly-use-get-context-data-with-listview-to-fetch-related-instances-in). I have three models:

```
class PartBase(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=120)
    price = models.DecimalField("Price per part", decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)       

class Sett(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=120)

class PartRelation(models.Model):
    part = models.ForeignKey(PartBase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qty = models.PositiveIntegerField("Quantity")
    sett = models.ForeignKey(Sett, related_name='setts', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def get_position_price(self):
        return self.qty * self.part.price
```

now I want to add the price of all the items in a Sett in a row in my HTML.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
    Add Set
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Set Name</th>
            <th>Total price</th>
        </tr>
    {% for set in setts %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ set.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ set.test }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

I wanted to override the get_context_data method somehow like this:

```
class SetListView(ListView):
    model = Sett
    context_object_name = "setts"

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(SetListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['test'] = "price"
        return context
```

But I only get an empty field in the template (which I assumed would have the word "price".

I can access the price in the shell via

```
for s in Sett.objects.all():
    pr = PartRelation.objects.filter(sett=s)
    price = 0
    for p in pr:
        price += p.get_position_price()
```

But how would I put the code from the shell in the `get_context_data()` function, so that for every row I get the corresponding total price?

Comment: Have you consider using `annotate()` https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate

Comment: you want to use price field but your sett model doesnt't have that field, if you want to use price field in your templates  then first add that field in your sett model or choose a different model that has price.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I solved it differently.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
class SetListView(ListView):
    model = Sett
    context_object_name = "setts"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SetListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        for s in context["setts"]:
            pr = PartRelation.objects.filter(sett=s)
            s.total_price = 0
            for p in pr:
                s.total_price += p.get_position_price()
        return context
```

I would gladly get feedback if that is a good approach (and why not/how to do better).